# How to collapse consecutive delimiters?

Tags: python, string, split

The default `split` method in Python treats consecutive spaces as a single delimiter.  But if you specify a delimiter string, consecutive delimiters are *not* collapsed:

```
>>> 'aaa'.split('a')
['', '', '', '']
```

What is the most straightforward way to collapse consecutive delimiters?  I know I could just remove empty strings from the result list:

```
>>> result = 'aaa'.split('a')
>>> result
['', '', '', '']
>>> result = [item for item in result if item]
```

But is there a more convenient way?

Comment: Seems like you could accomplish this with `re.split`

Comment: Interesting!  I didn't realize `split()` with no arguments did something that couldn't be replicated by `split` with arguments.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) with a regular expression as the delimiter, as in:

```
re.split(pattern, string[, maxsplit=0, flags=0])
```

Answer (score 27):

This is about as concise as you can get:

```
string = 'aaa'
result = [s for s in string.split('a') if s]
```

Or you could switch to regular expressions:

```
string = 'aaa'
result = re.split('a+', string)
```

Comment: Great solution! The pattern `a+` will split by the most consecutive `a` as possible. Thus, by running `re.split('a+',string)` it will return `['','']`. Say that `string = 'baaac'` then it would return `['b','c']`.

Comment: I put it in one more to get rid of any artefacts: `s = [s2 for s2 in [s.strip() for s in linkObj.getText().split('   ') if s] if s2]`

Comment: These solutions are not identical. The list comprehension solution ignores starting or ending delimiters. The regular expression solution does not ignore them, though it does collapse them. 
`assert ['', 'B', 'C', ''] == re.split('a+', 'aaBaaCaa')`

Answer (score 3):

You could use regular expressions:

```
re.split(pattern, string[, maxsplit=0, flags=0])
```

as

```
re.split('a+', 'aaa')
```

Comment: [Python's regex syntax](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax), if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution is perfectly OK. Here's an equivalent one:

```
filter(bool, 'aaa'.split('a'))
```

Probably not as perspicuous as a list comprehension, though.

Comment: sorry but this solution is pretty bad. Also, filter changed in python3 and won't have the same result

Comment: Can you elaborate on why it is bad (apart from that its behaviour changed in python 3 which I wasn't aware of)?

Comment: because you're adding a function call to bool (overhead) and making it less readable.

Comment: `filter` returns an iterator in Python 3 (as opposed to a list)―it uses less memory.

Comment: @Franklin I explicitely mentioned that it might be less readable than a list comprehension, but I see the point regarding the overhead. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Beau Martinez: I'm with you. I proposed the `filter` solution because the OP looks for a different solution than his own which already makes use of a list comprehension. Thanks for pointing out the difference between `filter` in Python 2 and 3, though. :)

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't a more convenient way. Either you write your own split function, or do the removing empty strings.

But your solution seems very clear and pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not exactly what you asked for, you can get rid of all non-unique tokens by using a `set`:

```
>>> result
['', '', '']
>>> set(result)
set([''])
```