# How to correctly split with multiple underscores?

Tags: python, string

I was wondering how to correctly split the string when you have an unknown number of underscores.
My input looks like this:

```
One Two_________1.0 2.0 3.0
Three Four______4.0 5.0 6.0
Five Six________7.0 8.0 9.0
```

Between words and numbers there is unknown number of underscores. I need to split this input into words and numbers. I tried using `split` in this way:

```
details = input.split("_")
words = details[0]
numbers = details[1]
```

However, it correctly saves only words. It worked when I changed the input to have only one underscore, however I just cannot find the solution when it has multiple underscores.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python split consecutive delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478845/python-split-consecutive-delimiters) or [How can I split by 1 or more occurrences of a delimiter in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492415/how-can-i-split-by-1-or-more-occurrences-of-a-delimiter-in-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use regexes for this.

```
import re
re.split('_+', 'asd___fad')
>>> ['asd', 'fad']
```

Basically, this is saying "split when you see one underscore (the underscore in `split`'s first arg) or more (the plus following that underscore)"

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem completely! This solution was easy to implement in my program and was clear to use.

Answer (score 0):

use negative indexing. I.E. numbers = details[-1]

Comment: you can use regular expressions (regexes) as well, but these can be complicated to implement if you don't understand what you're doing

Answer (score 0):

Using just builtins:

```
# slices input from beginning to first underscore
words = input[:input.find("_")]
# slices input from first underscore to the end, then replaces "_" with "".
numbers = input[input.find("_"):].replace("_", "")
```