# Python "split" function on repeated characters

Tags: python, string, split

I have gone through many threads on Stackoverflow about using Split function on strings, but still am unclear about the following output:

```
"aaaaa".split("a")
output: ['', '', '', '', '', '']

"baaaaa".split("a")
output: ['b', '', '', '', '', '']
```

Can someone please explain how repeated characters are treated by "split" function?

Comment: you can simplify this to "a" and "ba"

Comment: See the docs: [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split). They explain this exact situation: "If *sep* is given, consecutive delimiters are not grouped together and are deemed to delimit empty strings"

Comment: Related: [Python split consecutive delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6478845/4518341)

Answer (score 0):

The empty strings are not due to the fact that you have repeated characters but that in your string you have only the delimiter (the string by which you are splitting the target string). The output of `str.split` doesn't include the delimiter.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

> ```
> str.split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1)
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> If *sep* is given, consecutive delimiters are not grouped together and
>   are deemed to delimit empty strings (for example, `'1,,2'.split(',')`
>   returns `['1', '', '2']`). The *sep* argument may consist of multiple
>   characters (for example, `'1<>2<>3'.split('<>')` returns `['1', '2', '3']`). Splitting an empty string with a specified separator returns
>   `['']`.

Other way to see it:

1. Separate your string by the delimiter; you will get:

   ```
   "aaaaa" --> ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
   ```
2. Exclude the delimiter from your strings and you will get:

   ```
   ['', '', '', '', '']
   ```

In this manner, you will get your output similar to your second string.